# Java programming, encountered an infinite loop while solving. Image link to the question and the code is provided.

Tags: java, collections, infinite-loop

[RoyalGame Problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i2jtY.png)

The Image link to the problem is given above. I'm stuck in an infinite loop after the first iteration, can someone help me please. I'm open for alternate solutions as well, thanks in advance.

```
 static void compute(List<Integer> a){
        boolean henrystatus=false;
        while(true){
           if(a.size()==0){
           break;
        }
      else if(a.size()==1){
          henrystatus=true;
          break;
      }

       int mindex = a.indexOf(Collections.min(a));

     List<Integer> temp=new ArrayList<Integer>();
       for(int i=0;i<a.size();i++)
        {
           if(a.get(i)-mindex>0){
               temp.add(a.get(i)-mindex);
           }

        } 
       a.clear();
       a=temp;


        }
        if(henrystatus)
            System.out.print("Henry");
        else
            System.out.print("garry");

    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Small logical problem in your code because indexes in Java (or any programming language in general) start from zero, where naturally we count numbers from one. So when the minimum number was the first one, your `mindex` became zero due to which, zero (instead of actually one) was being subtracted in your array resulting into same array every time and was going in infinite loop.

So you just need to add one in your index while finding min index from your array.

Just change this line,

```
int mindex = a.indexOf(Collections.min(a));
```

to,

```
int mindex = a.indexOf(Collections.min(a)) + 1;
```

And your program will work just as you wanted and will no longer run into infinite loop.

Comment: The question requires us to subtract the container number having minimum number of coins. 
Suppose the input is as follows :
Number of containers = 5,
Coins in each container = 3 1 2 4 5. 
Since container 2 has minimum number of coins, we subtract 2 coins from each container, leaving us with 1,-1,0,2,3 coins in each container respectively.

Comment: Yes just read your full problem in image. Let me update my answer.

Comment: @ArzooHudda: Updated my post with the real cause of why it was going in infinite loop. Hope that clarifies.

Answer (score 1):

while(true) produces an infinite loop.

Comment: Yeah, there are two terminating conditions inside